# ensuring that a thread is completed before other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three threads t1, t2, t3. My need is to make t1 finish its work before t2 and t3 which are also simultaneously running.
How can i ensure this?
One method is via setting the threads priority, is there any other method to do the same.

Comment: what is the point of using multi-threading then?

Comment: Setting the threads' priority is _not_ a valid method. It's not guaranteed to do anything at all, let alone serialize your threads.

Comment: OP: Why do you need to make t1 finish before t2 and t2? Do t2/3 depend on t1 somehow? You need to provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

start them after `t1` finishes

for example

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

lock them all 3 on same object, if you have access to their `run()` method, and order doesn't matter for you

for example

```
Object lock = new Object();

public void run(){

 synchronized(lock){
   // have all run method this lock 
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you ensure that Thread2 does not get lock object before Thread1?

Comment: OP wants one by one, order doesn't matter for him AFAIK, @Sca

Comment: quote: My need is to make t1 finish its work before t2

Comment: updated answer, op can choose first approach

Comment: how to join both t2 and t3 after t1?